# Unable to access elasticsearch instance in Kibana while setting up by multinode cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

Unable to access elasticsearch instance in Kibana while setting up by multinode cluster by docker compose.

elasticsearch instance node are running fine.

Below I have shared the docker-compose.yaml and also the issue screenshot, can somebody help me on this.

Please let me know in case of any further information needed.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.8.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=elasticsearch2,elasticsearch3
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch,elasticsearch2,elasticsearch3
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - http.cors.enabled=true
      - http.cors.allow-origin=*
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - esnet
  elasticsearch2:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.8.1
    container_name: elasticsearch2
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch2
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=elasticsearch,elasticsearch3
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch,elasticsearch2,elasticsearch3
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - http.cors.enabled=true
      - http.cors.allow-origin=*
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet
  elasticsearch3:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.8.1
    container_name: elasticsearch3
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch3
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=elasticsearch,elasticsearch2
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch,elasticsearch2,elasticsearch3
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - http.cors.enabled=true
      - http.cors.allow-origin=*
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata3:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.8.0
    container_name: kibana
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: kibana.local
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch:9200
    ports:
      - '5601:5601'
    networks:
      - esnet

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
  esdata2:
    driver: local
  esdata3:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
    driver: bridge
```

**Error Screenshot**

[image]

**Error Screenshot**

[image]

Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the Elasticsearch nodes are available?

```
curl -XGET http://elasticsearch:9200/_cat/nodes?v
```

And also check which node is running as master

```
curl -XGET http://elasticsearch:9200/_cat/master?v
```

It may also be worth adding Elasticsearch as a dependency for Kibana in your docker-compose e.g.

```
kibana:
  image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.8.0
  container_name: kibana
  depends_on: elasticsearch
  environment:
    SERVER_NAME: kibana.local
    ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch:9200
  ports:
    - '5601:5601'
  networks:
    - esnet
```

Comment: found the cause the problem was due to initial heap size [536870912] not equal to the maximum heap size, made the same, then got worked

Answer (score 0):

initial heap size [536870912] not equal to the maximum heap size, made the same, then got worked.

Initial heap size and the maximum heap size must be equal